# Jquery & JSF find the particular id for <h:inputText/>

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am looking to match **id** for **inputText** in JSF using Jquery. But it does not work and I do not know why.

**JSF CODE**

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{userActionManager.newUser.emailID}">
</h:inputText>
```

---

### **Jquery CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("inputText[id^=email]").each(function(){

    this.value = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).addClass('text-label');

    $(this).focus(function(){
        if(this.value == $(this).attr('title')) {
            this.value = " ";
            $(this).removeClass('text-label');
        }
    });

    $(this).blur(function(){
        if(this.value == '') {
            this.value = $(this).attr('title');
            $(this).addClass('text-label');
        }
    });
});
});
```

I need inputText[id^=email] to be working to acces the inputText id used in JSF code.
Please Help...

Comment: It's been some time since I worked with JSF but doesn't inputText expand to a regular `input` tag? So you should use the jQuery on the generated HTML rather on the template compnents.

Comment: Rightclick JSF page in browser and choose *View Source*. Stare to it as long as until you finally realize that JSF is merely a HTML code generator and that JavaScript doesn't see JSF components at all, but only HTML elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly Id's on a page should be unique.

Next remove the `inputText tag` from the selector (`It is not a valid jQuery element selector`)

```
$("[id^=email]").each(function(){
```

You can also add class "email" to inputText and use class selector:

```
$(".email").each(function(){
```

Comment: need to change `<h:inputText id="email"` to `<h:inputText class="email"`

Comment: @user2446821, need to change `<h:inputText id="email"` to `<h:inputText styleClass="email"` (which will be transformed into html class="email")

Answer (score 1):

As Sushanth mentioned, you can not use `inputText` as a selector in jQuery. You must use `input` instead:

```
jQuery("input[type='text'][id^=email]:visible").each(...
```

Another point to check, is the **generated client ID**.
In fact, if in your form you are not specifying `prependId="false"` then the form ID will be added to the `inputText` id, ex: if form has `id="formId"` then, the generated ID for your input text will be, normally: `formId:email`. You have to inspect the ID using Chrome or Firebug to be sure.